# The method epli(String[]) in the type nammi is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, arguments

Im new to java and im just trying to use this method 'epli' from another class but when i try to do it it says 
`The method epli(String[]) in the type nammi is not applicable for the arguments ()`

im using eclipse here is all the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class nammi{
        public void epli(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Mér finnst nammi gott");
        }
    }

    public class siggi {
        public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Eg heiti ekki siggi");
            nammi nammi = new nammi();
            nammi.epli();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ps. standard java naming conventions is to use camel case, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase for class names. So nammi and siggi should have been: public class Nammi

Answer (score 2):

You defined **epli** as:

```
public void epli(String args[])
```

So you need to provide an String array when you call it.

If you change the signature of epli to

```
public void epli()
```

you can call it the way you are doing it

Answer (score 1):

Your method accepts a String[] data type but you are passing it nothing. You have to pass it a String[].

```
nammi.epli();
```

should become

```
nammi.epli(new String[5]);
```

or some other String array. You can also pass it a null if you want, but that's not what you should do in this case

```
nammi.epli(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the signature of the `epli()` method to use [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) syntax:

```
public void epli(String... args){
```

Within the `epli()` method, `args` will actually still has a type of `String[]`.

Now your calling code will work, and you can pass parameters like this:

```
nammi.epli(); // OK - args is an empty array (not a null)
nammi.epli("foo"); // args is array size 1
nammi.epli("foo", "bar"); // args is array size 2 etc
```